# SaveChangesAsync() not updating the database

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

So, I have this update method

```
var loanedAsset = await this.DB.Asset
                               .AsNoTracking()
                               .Where(Q => model.AssetIds.Contains(Q.AssetId)).ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in loanedAsset)
{
    item.IsLoanedBy = model.EmployeeId;
    await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

but, the value in database not updating. It still NULL
I'm sure that my `item` or `AssetIds` is not null, because i already check it manually. Even inside `foreach` the `item.IsLoanedBy` is assigned, but the only problem is, it wont update the database

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you should consider doing saveChangesAsync after the for loop in performance point of view also the other problem is .AsNoTracking() which causes the ef to stop tracking entity so when you update it the changes wont be tracked and wont be applied the best way to do so is this:

```
var loanedAsset = await this.DB.Asset
                               .Where(Q => model.AssetIds.Contains(Q.AssetId)).ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in loanedAsset)
{
    item.IsLoanedBy = model.EmployeeId;
    this.DB.Asset.Update(item);
    this.DB.Entry(item).State=EntityState.Modified;
}
await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
```